# Strain relief for a finished electrical panel

Tags: wiring, electrical-panel, code-compliance

I am going to run a new circuit from my QO electrical panel to my laundry room for a dedicated freezer plug. The panel is located in my garage and appears to be drywalled in all the way.

Here is a picture of the panel from when the house was being framed; sadly I don't have anything closer up than this. The style of strain relief clamp is visible on the top:

[image: Main Panel]

If I cannot easily access the top of the panel (as it is behind the drywall) then are there strain relief clamps that meet code which can be inserted from the inside?

Google has not been forthcoming and I haven't tackled an electrical panel before.

Comment: Have you thought about just removing some drywall(very carefully).  Imagine if a strain relief clamp is difficult, trying to get a cable to line up with a small hole with all those other cables in the way would be interesting.

Comment: @crip659 I have definitely given some thought to that! I have some decent fishing tools - a magnepull with a chain and a boroscope with a magnet that I have used to pull into some tight spots in the past... If I can avoid taking out drywall then I am going to do that but I'll do whatever it takes!

Comment: Just be careful.  Unless there is a disconnect before this box(at meter), there will still be live sections/parts in the box with just the main breaker off, you may touch by accident.

Comment: @crip659 Thank you! My main breaker is under the meter like you mentioned so I will be able to completely shut off the power to the panel. I also have a non-contact voltage tester that I will be using to ensure that nothing is live when I start working. I appreciate you mentioning that!

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're looking for.  It installs inside the box and allows for NM cable to be pushed in from either direction. I have used them often when cable had been installed into a panel without any connectors and inspections for insurance or selling required them to be added. See photo below.  They are made by Raco who I'm not affiliated with in any way.

[image]

Comment: Hey is [this link](https://www.hubbell.com/raco/en/Products/Electrical-Electronic/Fittings/Commercial-Fittings/12-in-THE-INSIDER-Nonmetallic-Sheathed-Cable-Connector/p/1658149) for the correct product? And thank you!

Comment: @Shrout1  Yep, that's it.

Comment: Yeah -- Arlington makes an equivalent in their White Button product if you can't find the Racos